# QNetworkAccessManager and authenticationRequired

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Help me write program work with protocol FTP and authentication by login password using QnetworkAccessManager. 
I implement connect to server and get directory listing, but i dont undestend how implement authentication. I read article http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/32/qq32-webkit-protocols.html.

My source in attach https://rapidshare.com/files/457472584/zip.zip.

Qt 4.7
Windows Xp
Linux

Comment: Why don't you use the QFtp class?

Comment: I use Qftp(see FtpReply class). But i want to do this with QNetworkAccessManager. It nned for my experiance ;).  Its impossible? May use be some workaround?

Answer (score 10):

I'm doing something similar and need to solve the very same problem: 
What I do is:
- create the **QNetworkAccessManager** object, and connect the signal **authenticationRequired**

```
m_ftpManagerPtr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
Q_ASSERT(m_ftpManagerPtr);
connect ( m_ftpManagerPtr,
          SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
          this,        
          SLOT(onAuthenticationRequestSlot(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)) );
```

Inside the slot function I simply populate the user name and password fields/variable:

```
void QacFtpClient::onAuthenticationRequestSlot(QNetworkReply *aReply, 
                                               QAuthenticator *aAuthenticator)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    aAuthenticator->setUser(m_ftpUser);
    aAuthenticator->setPassword(m_ftpPasswd);
}
```

And that's it... it automagically works ;)

Answer (score 8):

QUrl has a user/password field that you can use:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl url("host");
url.setUserName("user");
url.setPassword("password");

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
```

Comment: I thought this would be better than the QAuthenticator method and avoid the unnecessary 1st round trip just to be told to authorize, but looking at the source it seems it still waits for the request to fail before adding the authorization :(